# Graceful Handling of Technical PHP/SQL errors

Tags: php

I'm developing a PHP web application that is heavy on the database interactions.  My question is, how do I display "Pretty" errors.  I've got all kinds of exceptions and what not in pretty much every aspect of the app, but they still just awkwardly post the error text (which I currently have working perfectly) either above a half loaded page or on a blank, white background.

How do I go about rerouting these to a generic error page that has a nice, contained spot for inserting the error message so that clients and testers can communicate it to me.

My immediate guess would be to post these errors, but I don't know how to do that outside a form much less inside of a function.

Comment: what king of errors do you mean ? the "real" php errors like FATAL ERROR, WARNING and NOTICE ?

Comment: Those, in addition to pretty generic "user not found", "could not connect" and other bad data errors that may occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using exceptions, that's good.

You can prostpone all output using **[output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)**, and display all errors condensed at the required area of the page.

The actual technique revolves around simply appending all of the errors into an `$errors` array and iterating through it displaying nice errors along the way.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial you could link to for output buffering.  OB and I are old enemies.  He breaks my things, I randomly cut and paste until he goes away...